# How to serialize C# data to wp_postmeta (MySQL longtext column)

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to write a SQL update that takes part of a string and updates with part of another string (both strings already in the database).

My query looks like this, but it doesn't work :(

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 
      SELECT SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 23) AS meta_header 
             FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = 8443, 
      SELECT SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 23) AS meta_header 
             FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = 2037)
WHERE post_id = 8443
```

Any ideas for how to write it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain **but it doesn't work** ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 23) AS meta_header FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_i' at line 2

Comment: You can use group_concat to concat the data of the two matching rows and then update the table with the value... using replace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
replace into wp_postmeta (meta_id,meta_value) 
select 8443,concat(SUBSTRING(meta_value,1,23),t.end) 
from wp_postmeta JOIN 
(select SUBSTRING(meta_value,24) as end from wp_postmeta where meta_id=8443) as t
where meta_id=2037
```

Solution with group_concat:

```
replace into wp_postmeta (meta_id,meta_value) 
select 8443,group_concat(type SEPARATOR '') from 
 (select mem_id,substring(type,1,23) as type from wp_postmeta where mem_id=2037 
 UNION 
 select mem_id,substring(type,24) as type from wp_postmeta where mem_id=8443) as t;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'meta_id,meta_value 
select 8443,group_concat(SELECT SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 23)' at line 1

Comment: Add parenthesis around meta_id, meta_value changes the error to:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 23)  separator ',') 
       from wp_postmeta whe' at line 2

Comment: No errors, but it messes up the data. Using this query, I end up with "first 23 characters of 2037", "first 23 characters of 2037" and nothing else in meta_value

Comment: What is the final data that you want?

Comment: "8443 string start*rest of 8443 string" ---> "2037 string start*rest of 844 string" (X string start being the first 23 characters of what is actually a MySQL longtext column)

Answer (score 0):

Try this by joining your tables

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta wp1
JOIN wp_postmeta wp2 ON (wp1.meta_id =wp2.meta_id )
JOIN wp_postmeta wp3 ON (wp1.meta_id =wp3.meta_id )
SET wp1.meta_value = REPLACE(wp1.meta_value, SUBSTRING(wp2.meta_value, 1, 23) ,SUBSTRING(wp3.meta_value, 1, 23))
WHERE wp2.meta_id = 8443 AND wp3.meta_id = 2037
AND wp1.post_id = 8443
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE wp2.meta_id = 8443 AND wp3. meta_id = 2037
AND wp1.post_id = 8443
SET wp1.' at line 4

Comment: what is your mysql version ? and try my updated query

Comment: are you sure you do have a records with *post_id =8443 ,meta_id = 8443 and meta_id = 2037*

Comment: SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id IN (8443, 2037) return 8443 and 2037 (2 rows)

Comment: and what about **post_id =8443** also can you add the table definition and the sample dataset in [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/)